Can not install pandas in python 3.9
I am using python 3.9 with Spark.
python --version
Python 3.9.0

When I install pandas with
pip install pandas

I got the following error
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.2.2.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jw566d_g\pandas_b36c8476d5fa4a8dbafeeed465827c7c C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jw566d_g\pandas_b36c8476d5fa4a8dbafeeed465827c7c\.mesonpy-gh0nls41\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jw566d_g\pandas_b36c8476d5fa4a8dbafeeed465827c7c\.mesonpy-gh0nls41\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jw566d_g\pandas_b36c8476d5fa4a8dbafeeed465827c7c
      Build dir: C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jw566d_g\pandas_b36c8476d5fa4a8dbafeeed465827c7c\.mesonpy-gh0nls41\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.2.2

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Compiler cl cannot compile programs.

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\barba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jw566d_g\pandas_b36c8476d5fa4a8dbafeeed465827c7c\.mesonpy-gh0nls41\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

What could be causing this?

try python -m pip install --only-binary ":all:" pandas

can you post the lines that are printed when you run the python command?

It works. Thanks a lot

Try if any of the following works for you.

check if all the dependencies are installed properly.
upgrade the versions of pip setuptools and wheel
Try running the pip install command with the --pre option.

you can try installing different version of pandas
check the link for more options
[1]: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-preparing-metadata-pyproject-toml-did-not-run-successfully
